# Magento development learning curve

Tags: magento, backend, magento2

Our company just launched a new website based on Magento.  Me and my fellow developer have been working on asp.net and would start learning Magento.  Can anyone please explain where to begin.  What are the important points that we need to consider so we can manage and extend the website.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend this blog for understanding magento. Explained in the best and in-depth way.

> [magento blog by Alan storm](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento/)